# Реализация механизма пересоздания объектов классов, в случае выполнения цикла N раз в Java

Tags: java

Привет!

Необходимо реализовать механизм, который бы пересоздавал класс BattleField, если в классе Ship цикл выполнялся N раз.

Прошу подсказать лучшее и правильное решение для этого.

Ожидаю от программы:

ЕСЛИ в Ship.java цикл выполнялся N раз,
ТО в GameInitialization.java пересоздать объект класса BattleField и Fleet

```
//GameInitialization.java
    GameInitialization(){
        BattleField humanBattleField = new BattleField();
        Fleet humanFleet = new Fleet(humanBattleField);
    }

//Fleet.java
Fleet(BattleField battleField) {
    Ship[] fleet = new Ship[10];
    this.battleField = battleField;

    for (int i = 0; i < fleet.length; i++) {
        if (0 == i) {
            fleet[i] = new Ship(4, i, battleField);
            //do actions
        }
    }
}

//Ship.java
Ship(int shipLength, int shipNumber, BattleField battleField){
        while (false == isShipPlacementCorrect) {
            while (false == isInitialCoordinatesCorrect) {
                //do actions
            }         
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Будет проще, если выбор положения корабля возьмет на себя класс `Fleet`, а проверка возможности установки переедет в качестве метода в `BattleField` или во `Fleet`. Иначе единственный вариант сообщить вызывающему классу, что конструктор не смог - бросить исключение. Но это некрасиво, как и серьезная работа в конструкторе вообще. Чуть лучше был бы фабричный метод, который возвращал корабль в случае успеха и бросал исключение при неудаче, но все равно не очень.

Comment: @zRrr так и есть: Ship циклом генерит координаты и проверяет можно ли расположить самого себя на поле, возвращает true. После Fleet вызывает метод BattleField и располагает корабль на поле. Иногда случается ситуация, когда этот цикл Ship уходит практически в бесконечность, так как не может найти свободные координаты для расположения. И я не знаю, как лучше всего с эти бороться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ship(int shipLength, int shipNumber, BattleField battleField){
   int counter = 0;
    while (false == isShipPlacementCorrect) {
        while (false == isInitialCoordinatesCorrect) {
            if (counter >= N) {
                 counter=0;
                 // пересоздаем
            }
            counter+=1;
            //do actions
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Как из Ship удалить текущий и создать новый BattleField?